# terminal server 2003, changed location of user profile "Desktop" items

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

have a terminal server 2003 that about 50users can use, users are saving documents on the desktop, today users complain that documents on the desktop is missing, no upgrades or changes  has been done

the error is that the server reverted to load items the folder name "Desktop" instaed of using the local language "Skrivbord" (swedish for desktop)

So the files are still on the server located under the users swedish folder name, but server does not load it, server however does load files located under the English folder name

how can the terminal server from one day to another just change from where it loads the user profile desktop files?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Event Viewer to see if a Windows Update was loaded? Something had to change. I would guess that either a patch was loaded that caused this behavior or someone changed the localization settings on the server by mistake.